# VERILATOR: Terminal stuck after execution of helloworld SystemVerilog, with C++ wrapper

Tags: c++, verilator

I am new to Verilator and encountered a problem with basic HelloWorld example. I was following the **[Verilator Manual](https://www.veripool.org/ftp/verilator_doc.pdf)** and wanted to execute the basic Helloworld example with C++ wrapper program **(2.1 Example C++ Execution)**. After invoking command

```sh
verilator -Wall --cc --exe --build sim_main.cpp our.v
```

an `obj_dir` directory was created with generated C++ code and after running `Vrun` file, my terminal gets stuck,blocked..whatever..does nothing.

I always have to CTRL-c and cancel it afterwards.
I also tried with not using the `-build` in the command, and I manually compiled it. And still to no avail.

Has anyone encountered a problem like this, or does someone have any idea what is wrong? I'm using Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS, and Verilator version 4.211 devel rev v4.210-78-g27d53691

Thanks.

Note: I had no problems during installation

Comment: You can try command like:  verilator -Wall --trace -cc sim_main.cpp our.v

Comment: @Mihai8 Tried that command, and afterwards I tried to make it all again, but I got thousands of errors, and all of them originate from **include/verilated_types.h** and every error has different **line_number:position** I.e. one error looks like this:

/usr/local/share/verilator/include/verilated_types.h:639:30: error: ‘m_map’ was not declared in this scope
  639 |         for (const auto& i : m_map) {

Answer (score 0):

I found that I just named "our.v" to "out.v". I corrected the file name and solved it. :)